# How do I install XBMC?

Tags: multimedia, xbmc

Where can I get XBMC for Ubuntu?

I have the team-xbmc ppa added however they have no packages, is there an older deb or is there somewhere where i can get the source and build myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

#### For Ubuntu 12.04 and newer

Click on the button:

[image: Install via the software center]

or by simply opening a terminal and typing `sudo apt-get install xbmc`.

After the release of Ubuntu 12.04 updates should be available in the stable XBMC PPA above and XBMC can be updated by adding the PPA and updating your system.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Should note that sound will not work correctly (HDMI for example and 5.1 Intel motherboards) and issues with MKV files still exist in 12.04 and 12.10 if I use this way (Apart from many more problems). This is why I posted the other answer below.

Answer (score 8):

The [main XBMC PPA](http://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ppa) has been updated with the latest stable releases.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile xbmc in Ubuntu, the following worked for me:

## Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install git-core make g++ gcc gawk pmount libtool nasm yasm automake cmake gperf zip unzip bison libsdl-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libfribidi-dev liblzo2-dev libfreetype6-dev libsqlite3-dev libogg-dev libasound2-dev python-sqlite libglew-dev libcurl3 libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libmad0-dev libogg-dev libvorbisenc2 libsmbclient-dev libmysqlclient-dev libpcre3-dev libdbus-1-dev libhal-dev libhal-storage-dev libjasper-dev libfontconfig-dev libbz2-dev libboost-dev libenca-dev libxt-dev libxmu-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libpulse-dev mesa-utils libcdio-dev libsamplerate-dev libmpeg3-dev libflac-dev libiso9660-dev libass-dev libssl-dev fp-compiler gdc libmpeg2-4-dev libmicrohttpd-dev libmodplug-dev libssh-dev gettext autopoint cvs python-dev libyajl-dev libboost-thread-dev libplist-dev libusb-dev libudev-dev
```

## Downloading And Compiling xbmc

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git xbmc
cd xbmc
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

---

## Ubuntu 12.04(final)

although you can install xbmc in 12.04 via software-center or `sudo apt-get install xbmc`, for those that want to compile xbmc in 12.04, for whatever reason(Like to see code pass by in the gnome-terminal for that geeky feel) Here is the code which enables said feeling.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xbmc
cd
git clone git://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git xbmc
cd xbmc
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Note**: Reboot after compiling for the XBMC icon to appear!

**Source**:

- [XBMC from source - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/xbmc-from-source)

Answer (score 1):

[XBMC - HOW-TO:Compile XBMC on Debian/Ubuntu](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO_compile_XBMC_for_Linux_on_Debian/Ubuntu)
I don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04 & 12.10 you can use the following PPA from here: [XBMC Nightly : Nathan Rennie-Waldock](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/xbmc-nightly)

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/xbmc-nightly`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install xbmc`

I recommend this one because:

- No need to compile anything
- Does not have dependencies issues with other packages
- Solves an audio problem I was having with HDMI
- Performance is MUCH better when having many movies (More than 900+ Movies)
- Searching for Movie Data (Cover Art, Actor Information...) is MUCH faster
- Loading and Reading are better
- Respects Widescreen resolutions
- Sound quality is better
- BAD - It will appear almost daily to update since it is a Daily PPA which is why I recommend that, after downloading it the first time, Disable or ignore the PPA for a week at least. No sense in updating it everyday.

This are the problems I was having with XBMC that came with 12.04. This is because most of this problems are fixed in the Git repository but not yet applied to a stable release. This version however is very stable for me. Tested with 900+ movies, 8000+ songs and 17 TV series. Downloaded cover arts for all, lyrics, subtitles, etc.. No problem, not even one. The remote controller for android also worked perfectly.