# Install XBMC on Natty?

Tags: 11.04, xbmc

I am having trouble installing the media centre XBMC on Natty.

I have added the sources and got a 404 error.

Is there a way of installing XBMC onto Natty?

Cheers

Comment: Probably they don't have a package for natty yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-install-xbmc) to add the Software Source ppa for XBMC.

Then edit the software source and change the distribution from natty to maverick as per this picture.

[image]

Comment: looking at your screenshot I wonder if there's already a bug filed regarding the captured pixels of the background

Comment: I'm using "gnome-screenshot" which is part of the gnome-utils package.  I'm not sure whether there is a launchpad area for this, or if this is in the gnome-bugzilla website.  Good question, well asked - dont know the answer!