# Install Acire and Python Snippets

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Acire and Python Snippets in Ubuntu 11.04 (64-bit).

I have successfully installed Acire, but I'm unable to install the python-snippets package. Both PPA's have been added to my sources list, but when I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/python-snippets-drivers/python-snippets-daily/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

What should I do to install python-snippets?

Comment: Thanks to Lifeling I was able to install Acire under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Although there is another missing dependancy, python-vte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this PPA - https://launchpad.net/~python-snippets-drivers/+archive/python-snippets-daily - there are packages only for Lucid and Maverick.  No packages yet for Natty.

Suggest either contact the package owner (one Jorge O Castro!) or try editing your software sources and changing "natty" to "maverick" as per this [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41226/install-xbmc-on-natty)

Comment: There are no packages for Maverick either, but changing "natty" to "lucid" did the trick!

Comment: you mean @JorgeCastro, right?

Comment: yep - have a look at the author of the package ... I wonder what the O is for!

Answer (score 0):

There is also another PPA with the python-snippets package built specifically for Natty.The only place I could find one that was suitable for Natty was in Matthieu Baerts’ PPA. You can add the source and install python-snippets with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:matttbe/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-snippets
```

After this Acire does have a dependency on the desktopcouch package. You can get the desktopcouch package from the Software center or use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install desktopcouch
```

Now you should have all the packages you need. you can run Acire from the command line by just typing “acire” It should also appear on your menu, in the programming category. If you are using unity you should be able to use the main lens to find and run Acire.