# Install Acire and Python Snippets on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: python, quickly

This [site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48932/install-acire-and-python-snippets) is out of date - I'm using Ubuntu 14.

Is there an alternative for Ubuntu 14?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions provided from the Acire website? http://aciresnippets.wordpress.com/install/