# Update Manager saying check your internet connection...How do I fix this so it can update?

Tags: update-manager, updates

Here are the details it gave me as causing the problem:

```
W:Failed to fetch http:// dowload.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/maverick/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'dowload.virtualbox.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
, W:Failed to fetch http:// dowload.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/maverick/contrib/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'dowload.virtualbox.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
, W:Failed to fetch http://dowload.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/maverick/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'dowload.virtualbox.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
, W:Failed to fetch http:// dowload.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/maverick/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'dowload.virtualbox.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
, W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/elegant-gnome/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/elegant-gnome/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Natty - in your *Software Sources*

`W:Failed to fetch http:// dowload.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/maverick/Release.gpg`

you've got two issues:

1. a typo "dowload" - I would have expected "download".
2. you are using a "maverick" repo - but are on natty.

`W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources`

There is not a natty repository availabile - you will need to change this to "maverick"

see my linked answer below

`W:Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/elegant-gnome/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources 404`

There is not a natty repo available - can I suggest don't use this PPA?

---

Linked Question:

1. [Install XBMC on Natty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41226/install-xbmc-on-natty)

Comment: gah that's embarrassing. I think I'll blame my tiny keyboard for the misspelling. But that fixed it, Thanks :)

Comment: @Allison - excellent news - please click the tick button to accept and close the question.