# why isn't xbmc media center in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, xbmc

i've been a long-time user of XBMC (and sometimes Boxee, but it's full of bugs..), and i wondered: it's open source, it's a stable software, and yet it's not in USC. why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XBMC is now included in the Ubuntu Software Centre for Ubuntu 12.04.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I install XBMC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-install-xbmc)

Comment: Alt, point directly to the source which that articles seems based on? http://xbmc.org/theuni/2012/04/10/xbmc-accepted-into-debian/

Answer (score 2):

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=469397 for an in-depth explanation.

Some excerpts:

> Which license/issue are you referring to? Last I checked, all these 
>   problematic licenses had clauses like "you can't use this for
>   commercial  purposes", "you must send us patches upon request", or
>   some other stupid  clause like "you must not code on any Monday at
>   3:05pm in someone else's  bedroom".
>
> Even if XBMC were changed to LGPL, BSD, or whatever, I don't see how
>   that will  help with the third party code with these other
>   restrictions.
>
> So as far as I know, XBMC is at least distributable. It just
>   unfortunately has  some code that contains other restrictions like
>   these nagging non-commercial  clauses, which is keeping it from going
>   to main.

Also:

> They conflict with the GPL, so they keep it from being uploaded to
>   Debian at all.

---

The licensing issues have been fixed, but nobody cared to bring it into debian since then. Ubuntu is mostly build on debian packages.

Comment: Launchpad question opened: https://answers.launchpad.net/xbmc/+question/177432 and i'm planning to bring it up as a bug as well.. thanks for all the comments