# XBMC-live (Ubuntu based) setting up tty8

Tags: xorg, gdm, tty, xbmc

I'm running XBMC-live which is an Ubuntu distro with Xbox media center (XBMC) as the default window manager.  I'm trying to leave XBMC set up on tty7, as it is, and have a normal window manager on added for tty8, so I can use a web browser and stuff.  The guides I found for setting up tty8 all use gdm configure files, but I don't even have gdm installed and installing gdm wants me to remove xbmc-live, which is definetly not what I want.  Any tips how I can set up tty8 to be a regular wm given these conflicts?  I don't really even need tty8 to have a login like gdm, it could just directly launch a window manager.

Comment: Interesting setup. I think I will try a similar setup once I upgrade my media center box to a more powerful machine.

Comment: This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I dont have this setup yet but I dont think you need to install gdm. You should be able to install gnome, xfce, kde or any other desktop environment without the desktop manager that comes with it. You can then either manually start that desktop session after switching to tty8 or write an script to automatically load it.

I suppose you have already seen [this question on installing XBMC in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-install-xbmc). Although it is not exactly the path you want to take, it shows that XBMC and gnome can coexist perfectly fine.

Comment: Everything I've tried adding seems to conflict with xbmc-live... "apt-get install xubuntu-desktop"(which is xfce), "... gnome", "... gdm", etc. all want to uninstall xbmc-live as part of the process.