# How do I get the Ultimate Ubuntu Home System?

Tags: home-server, media-manager, media

Good Day,

I am relatively new the Ubuntu world but I am loving it. I am a huge supporter of open source software, open access, and anything that can relate to these concepts. I am tired of paying big industry boodles of money for stuff that I cannot even really do what I want. So, this is my question(s).

How do I create the ultimate Ubuntu home system? Maybe open source would be a better use as I am new to this area, there might be something better for this than Ubuntu. Let me explain what it is that I want to do. Please remember that although I am new to this area, I am a do-it your self kind of person, so a lot of work to get what I want doesn't bother me.

I want a sweet customizable entertainment system. I see there are things out there like MythTV for recording shows. I want to be able to do that, but I also want to be able to access an external hard drive that has digital movies on it, music, photos, and who knows what else. I want to be able to watch internet tv shows and YouTube without the stupid blocks that come on Google TV and Xbox where it won't let you watch some videos. I want it to be networked with other devices in my house and have a home server storing all of this information in one spot so it accessible even without an internet connection. If I can get it to work with lighting and other electronics that would be great.

Perhaps there are some other things out there that I am not even aware of...as I said, I'm new. I have a LAMP server running on my laptop locally and it was pretty easy to set up. I am working on numerous open source softwares that require that server so I am somewhat familiar with it.

I am really looking for a cool do it all kind of system that runs through out the whole house, has central storage, and customizable interfaces for each specific job. I hope I am making myself understood. Please feel free to ask any questions and I look forward to reading your posts! Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend Kodi (formerly XBMC) with various addons from https://www.tvaddons.ag/

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be one of the solutions for you...

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)

- [How do I install XBMC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-install-xbmc)

Answer (score 2):

Type in terminal

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install xbmc

You can even have XBMC to start on Login by selecting XBMC session while logging into LightDM

Comment: your PPA is out-of-date and is only applicable to maverick and below.

Comment: I am definately going to play with XBMC but i was looking for something more complex and on a grander scale. XBMC may be part of the solution, but it is bigger than just a media player. You see people who have everything tied to their phones - lights, tv, thermostat and so forth. I want a system like that. A system that I can access any of my files from anywhere in the world. I want to turn down my heat from work, set up a show to record from my phone while at a dinner party. Then have the option to watch it on my tv, computer, or phone while it is just being stored on one location.